# Check a checkbox if it's unchecked, dont allow it to be unchecked if it's checked

Tags: jquery

Here is my attempt with all checkboxes having having the check class. I know from console logs that the clicks are happening. For some reason in chrome, this doesn't work (checkbox remains unchecked

```
$('#parent').delegate('.check', 'click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if!($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most. Confusing. Title. Ever.

Comment: why checkbox use radio instead...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#parent').delegate('.check', 'click', function (event) {
    if (!this.checked) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/btmrT/)

Comment: I'm surprised the way it's working. the condition is if not checked then prevent the default, but it's working as if checked prevent the default. How does this work???